# Treating subclass reference as Object

Tags: java, polymorphism

This is polymorphism related question raised in process of learning Java.

Example has two classes: `AA` as a parent and `BB` as a child. We create two references to child object - one in a parent class variable and second in a child class variable:

```
  AA aa = new BB();
  BB bb = new BB();
```

In case we call **child** method via **parent reference** and pass **child** type variable, it is  treated as `Object`.

```
  aa.equals(bb);  //call BB.equals (Object ob)
```

Why? Why does kind of variable which invokes method influence parameter type identification?

Here is a full code:

```
public class AA
{
}

public class BB extends AA
{
    public boolean equals (Object ob){
       .............
    }

    public boolean equals (AA ob){
       .............
    }

    public boolean equals (BB ob){
       .............
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] params) {
        {
            AA aa = new BB();
            BB bb = new BB();

            System.out.println(aa.equals(bb)); //call BB.equals (Object ob)  Why? 
            System.out.println(bb.equals(bb)); //call BB.equals (BB ob)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: when you assign a reference to a wider type -- e.g. when you write `AA aa = new BB();`, you are telling the compiler to *forget* that `aa` is a `BB()`.  It is just an `AA` now, as far as the compiler is concerned, because you told the compiler to treat it as an `AA`.

Next: `AA` only has one `equals` method, the one inherited from `Object`: `equals(Object)`.

Next: `BB` overrides that method with `equals(Object)`, so that implementation gets called.

(This is one of many reasons it is almost never a good idea to define any `equals` method *other* than `equals(Object)`.)